# Find pattern in Notepad++

Tags: regex, csv, notepad++

I'm using Notepad++ to look at a broken CSV that won't import.

The pattern should be:

```
"text","text","text","text","text","text","text","text",date
```

Is there a way in Notepad++ to find lines that **do not match** this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(?!"[^"]*"(?:,"[^"]*")*,[\d\/]*$).+$
```

Use a negative lookahead. See [this regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/vD0sJ3/2).

Comment: Hi. Sorry I didn't mean a literal `"text"`, I meant that it could be text. For example `"one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight",01/01/2015`.

Comment: Found 3 broken rows, saved me a days work of looking through 73,000 rows ;-)

Comment: @Jack cool :) seems regex is useful sometimes in real world:P

Answer (score 0):

One thing that might work, depending on what you want to do with the result, is to simply find and remove all the correct instances. This leaves you with the broken lines. If you do this in a copy, you can then use the result to search for exact matches and find the locations in the original file.